# When an Uchiha member is going to get married with another Uchiha member, are they marrying their cousin?

Tags: naruto

Like my question is asking, are they marrying their own cousin? I'm wondering this because I remember Obito telling Naruto that Sasuke was his relative in volume 71 chapter 683: I Dreamt the Same Dream. I also remember Madara saying the same thing to Sasuke and Obito, which got my attention.

So according to what I've read in the manga they are saying their blood is all connected which, therefore, makes them all relative? So if they are relatives that make them cousins or something like that? If they do end up being cousins, are they marrying their own cousin? Isn't that kind of disturbing to them or am I wrong and in the Uchiha there are still different family members but have the same last name, which makes them all "relatives"?

Comment: [Everyone on earth is actually your cousin...](http://qz.com/557639/everyone-on-earth-is-actually-your-cousin/) so yeah :P

Comment: Well, the Uchiha have a common ancestor, Indra Otsutsuki. I don't suppose the Uchiha have some sort of uneasiness when marrying another Uchiha, because, basically, the roots are too deep. Also, about your aforementioned chapter citation, the copy I checked has a translation of Obito's dialogue in this manner: "[I am] an Uchiha like Sasuke..". It doesn't directly imply that they are blood relatives

Comment: In Korean tradition, it is actually forbidden to marry someone of the same last name as you. Last names had been continuously used in Korea for several millenia... do the math. (The most common one, Kim, has over a million members, including the current North Korean leader.)

Comment: "Incest is Wincest" - Some Random Greek Guy :v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are. They probably know it. And they aren't that closely related, anyway.

It had often been the case, historically, in noble and especially royal families to marry within the family (often to fairly close relatives) - either because marriage to a lower class was too low in status and there just wasn't much of the higher class, or simply to keep the money in the family. (A particularly silly example is the Ptolemaic dynasty of Egypt.)
It even happened in non-noble families too; somewhat famously, the maiden name of Franklin Roosevelt's wife, Eleanor Roosevelt, was also Roosevelt (she was Theodore Roosevelt's daughter), though their common ancestor was six generations away.

In the case of the Uchiha clan, it actually makes sense - they want to maximize the chance of their bloodline manifesting in the progeny. And given how large the clan is (or, at least, how large it was before Itachi wrecked it all up), chances are that, in many cases, there are quite a few generations to the nearest common ancestor.
I suspect that the Uchiha elders actually did try to make sure not to marry especially close relatives, to minimize inbreeding problems; given how crazy many of the Uchiha members ended up being... for all we know, they still failed, and the last few Uchihas did suffer from inbreeding in their ancestry.

Answer (score 2):

In a way, but not necessarily. All 3 of them, Obito, Madara, and Sasuke, Are Uchiha after all, so they are somewhat closely related, but that does not mean their parents or grandparents were the same people. It only means that when you go way back they have some lineage to Indra, but that was dozens of generations earlier. It is entirely possible for Indras kids to spread out enough that you could have groups of families whos only connection between them and any other uchiha is Indra. They probably did also sometimes marry outside of the Uchiha which would help diversify the gene pool.

Really though, so long as you avoid your siblings and your Cousins, the problem of inbreeding is nearly nonexistent anyway. Based on what was shown, the clan was probably a few hundred strong before the massacre, so there would most likely be plenty of uchiha to choose from without inbreeding being a real problem. Certainly it would occasionally happen, but When it comes to those 3 specifically, there is likely no major relation. Madara might be a great great uncle to them, and Obito and Sasuke might be direct cousins, but that is the closest we can speculate considering we know Obitos parents are not Sasukes, but not the relationship between either set of parents, And Madara and his brothers had no known children, ending his direct family bloodline.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but not really anymore than if two British people with the surname "Smith" got married. They were a clan (and likely a large one) so as long as they avoided marriages with anyone more closely related than a third cousin, they shouldn't have had to worry too much about inbreeding.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all Uchiha except for the women that marry into the clan are related. So when an Uchiha marries another Uchiha then he or she is marrying a relative. But take note that since the Uchiha clan and other clans in the Naruto universe are quite large many of the clan members are distantly related, with the most recent ancestor or ancestral pair being generations and generations before their time, so it's most probably the case that the clans from Naruto don't suffer the issues of inbreeding since in most cases the closest relative an Uchiha or Hyuga is marrying is a second or third cousin, with more distant relatives being more common marruage partners, which doesn't cause the problems of sibling or first cousin inbreeding but does continue the progeny at an almost as steady rate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  a family is a unit consisting of parents and children, a clan is a group of interrelated families who share a common ancestor and common goals. before Boruto the clan system in naruto was based around feudal japan. in feudal japan women marrying into a clan didn't take the clan name. as such before boruto anyone with the name Uchiha was Uchiha by blood. 
the Uchiha like all clans with a Kekkei Genkai married almost exclusively with other Uchiha this was to preserve the Sharingan from not only getting outside of the Uchiha clan but to preserve its power
and interbreeding with cousins isn't against the law in most places because the chances of producing a child with a birth defect with a 1st cousin is at max about 3 or 4%

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the clans are inbred. When Itachi massacred the whole clan we don't see the sharingan in anyone but people who's names are Uchiha (expect Kakashi, but he got his from Obito). Females can inherit the Sharingan, as seen with Sarada so it's safe to assume they can pass it down to their descendants. Since females tend to take their husband's name and their children too, those hypothetical non-Uchihas can inherit the Sharingan but there aren't any. Not to mention Itachi's girlfriend was also an Uchiha. They may not be closely related, but they still share common ancestors. It doesn't mean that Uchihas only marry in their clan, but likely most do. 
Same with the Hyuuga clan, everyone's eyes are blank and pupil-less, but Hinata's kids with Naruto have blue eyes. Their kids also have the Byakugan, so eye techniques can likely passed down from females. This also proves the Sharingan can be passed down by females too.