# Inter-Clan Marriage?

Tags: naruto

Although it's never a rule, it seems the standard throughout Naruto that Ninjas married within their own clan so as to preserve their Kekkei Genkai (Hyuuga) or just to preserve the blood lines (Uzumaki). (This can still be broken as is the case between Minato and Kushina.)

It seems though, that in the final chapter, all the Ninja of the 'Konoha 11' seem to marry outside of their clan, like Naruto and Hinata (Uzumaki and Hyuuga) or Shikamaru and Temari (Nara and Sand). I understand that this was more of a fan service chapter, but is there any in-universe explanation as to why none of the Ninja of Naruto's generation decided to marry in-clan?

Comment: *Probably* because incest is illegal in most universes?

Comment: As i know Hyuuga is the only one that had the rule of marrying within their own clan(not sure for uchiha). hashirama's wife was an uzumaki, though there has not be any explanation about the marriage of the parent of the Konoha 11 parents. They might had inter clan marriage. they might not be the one who had inter clan marraige

Comment: @Makoto [Is it?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31064/when-an-uchiha-member-is-going-to-get-married-with-another-uchiha-member-are-th)

Comment: @Makoto marriage within their own clan doesn't mean within in one famiy

Comment: Anyways, not a definite answer, but the inclusive of inner-clan marriages is possibly designed to be a symbol of unity. After the Fourth Great Shinobi War, the [5 nations](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Five_Great_Shinobi_Countries) were no longer enemies and worked together under the [Shinobi Union](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinobi_Union)

Answer (score 1):

It is true that shinobi clans married within their respective clan so that their Kekkei Genkai would remain in the family. But it was around the time when all the nations were at war with each other. Once Hashirama Senju decided to distribute all the tailed beasts among the hidden villages, the majority of attention (of bad people) shifted from obtaining bloodline limit techniques to obtaining/controlling tailed beasts.

Also, in case of interclan marriages, it was not sure that the offspring would awaken his/her Bloodline Limit. It was evident in the case of Tsunade's parents who were half Senju and half Uzumaki because very little is known about them, but it was certain that they were no shinobi.

The concept of not having interclan marriages was high when nations were at war and having a technique unique to only one family/clan meant that their country would have an advantage over the enemy. Like in the case of Kimimaro's Clan. But since it was evident that every offspring couldn't awaken their bloodline limit, interclan marriages were often held.

In the case of the Uchiha, there was never any protocol to marry within Uchiha. Because their Kekkai Genkai was not easy to awaken, even for those who were descendants of great Uchiha shinobi. Even if someone from outside their clan awakened the Sharingan, it would do a great deal of damage to one's body and eventually lead to death (as in Kakashi's case where he was paralyzed for an entire week after using his Mangeky Sharingan to save Gaara. Luckily by the end of Kaguya's Arc Obito helped him control his Sharingan but it drained out his stamina quickly).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the post-War wake was a definitive change in mindset among all Ninja. What was once taboo was finally available at no negative cost to the individual. Therefore, when the surviving clan members mate it is only natural that they would all utilize their newfound freedoms as opposed to sticking to the harsh, restricting rules of the past. Its all symbolic of the change Naruto set into motion.